# OpenLaszlo 5.0.x - HTML5 compile issues

Tags: openlaszlo, laszlo

I know this has got to be something stupid as it use to work...

We have an app that works great in V4.2.0.4... some time ago (year or so) we started playing in the nightly builds and seeing how well our apps work under the HTML5 runtime. After much playing around an a few coding changes, we got there. Still some differences we're trying to work through, but all in all we got it working. The nightly build I was using was from the last one in 2011.

So with all the improvements that have come through, we thought we'd try the newest and see if some of the things we were trying to work around have been fixed. After upgrading, it's looking good until we create the solo version. Once we create the solo when we compile it, we get tons of redefining errors and the solo version also doesn't load at all, I'm guessing the redefining errors are causing problems.

Thinking since it's the new nightly build thats the issue, I go back to the previous version that we had that was working for us. But the issue continues to happen... I don't know how it's possible when our specific code didn't change.

If we make a coding change, even adding a space somewhere, it will compile without the redefining errors again until we create the solo, then they are back.

I'm at a complete loss. We didn't make code changes on our end so if nothing else the version we were using for the past year should still at least preform as before? What am I missing or being dumb about? Any ideas?

Sorry can't really do any code snippit as it's on a whole application type thing.

Here are a few of the errors.. all point to LFCdhtml-debug.js (line 698)

ERROR:

Redefining $lzc$class__mvd from () to () (an empty string)
LFCdhtml-debug.js (line 698)

ERROR:

Redefining $lzc$class__mve from () to () (an empty string)
LFCdhtml-debug.js (line 698)

ERROR:

Redefining $lzc$class__mw8 from () to () (an empty string)
LFCdhtml-debug.js (line 698)

ERROR:

Redefining $lzc$class__mw9 from () to () (an empty string)
LFCdhtml-debug.js (line 698)

I use the developer console to create the solo. Is the command line tool better? Haven't had a chance to use it.

I will try the lzt=clearcache and see if it helps.

Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Could you add the exact error message you are seeing to your question? Look in the browser JavaScript console, and add the error message and location to your question (in case it's a location inside the LFC). How do you create the SOLO application? Do you use the developer console, or the command line `lzdeploy` tool? Did you try to clear the LPS cache by using the `lzt=clearcache` parameter?

Comment: I am not sure if this is related to your problem or not but I have encountered a similar problem occasionally where simply adding a space in the code will fix strange errors even in the official 4.9.0 version. Try clearing the OpenLaszlo cache and restarting the OpenLaszlo services, sometimes it helps fix that kind of problem. You can clear the cache by passing lzt=clearcache to the solo app (see: http://www.openlaszlo.org/lps4.9/docs/deployers/request-types.html#d0e142185 for more details)

Comment: added response to raju above as it was hard to read in this comment section.

Comment: so if I build everything with debug off, it seems to be working, but that isn't very useful in modifing the app. And it doesn't explain why I didn't have the issue until I tried a newer nightly build even though I've gone back to what I was using to start with! I feel so stupid but it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AmyFriedrichsDeVries If you are seeing strange effects after going back to a previous version of OpenLaszlo in DHTML runtime, make sure to clear the browser cache. The browser might still load the old LFC version which is causing the errors.

Comment: Thanks Raju, but that is standard practice just to be sure even though settings say to always clear then. I have even stopped tomcat and restarted it to make sure there is nothing lingering there. I really have no answer but have moved on for the time being as I can work around it to at least get our changes done. Maybe I'll come back to it if I have 'extra' time at some point. Thanks again everyone for the suggestions.